# How to Speed Up Two-Pass Encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a `Video` file with `Audio`, `Subtitles`, `Chapters`, and `Metadata`.

I removed `Audio` and `Subtitles` with `-an -sn` from `-pass 1` and then inlclude them in `-pass 2`.

What about for `Chapters` and `Metadata`? And how do you apply `Turbo` to `-pass 1`?

Is there anything more that can be done?

---

I have a script that will convert `mpg` to `mp4`. I've sorted it with linebreaks so it's easier to read.

**Pass 1**

```
"C:\Videos\example.mpg" 

-vcodec libx264 
-preset medium -b:v 2500K -pix_fmt yuv420p -qcomp 0.8 
-vf scale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" 
-pass 1 

-map 0:v:0? -an -sn

-threads 8 

"C:\Videos\example.mp4"
```

**Pass 2**

```
ffmpeg -y -i 

"C:\Videos\example.mpg" 

-vcodec libx264 
-preset medium -b:v 2500K -pix_fmt yuv420p -qcomp 0.8 
-vf scale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" 
-pass 2 

-acodec aac 
-b:a 320k 
-af volume=1.2 

-map 0:v:0? -map 0:a:0? -map 0:s? -c:s copy -map_metadata 0 

-threads 8 

"C:\Videos\example.mp4"
```

Comment: Try faster presets.

Comment: Omit `-threads 8`. libx264 will automatically choose the appropriate value. Make sure your ffmpeg and x264 are not ancient. Check the console output and ensure that it does not show `using cpu capabilities: none!`. Consider using single pass encoding with `-crf` instead of two-passes.